# Sql Server Compact Edition. OleDb crashes when insert into table

Tags: insert, sql-server-ce, oledb

I have created **table Sellers** with columns

```
Id - int, primary key, identity
FullName - nvarchar(100)
Password - nvarchar(100)
```

When I try to insert a row into table console application crashes with no chance to catch exception.

```
var command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Sellers (FullName, Password) VALUES(?, ?)", DbConnection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", fullName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please, tell me what I do wrong?

Selects work ok for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use of the Managed OledDB provider against SQL Server Compact is not supported, use the dedicated ADO.NET Provider (System.Data.SqlServerCe) or use the DbProvider objects.